# How to filter a variable query option with regex?

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

I want to create a variable in grafana that queries all Subscriptions but filters subscriptions that start with a specific text.

[image]

Some results I see by default are like:
`Dig-dev, Dig-uat, Dig-prod, ndr-eu-pp-dev, ndr-eu-pp-uat, ndr-eu-pp-prod`

Let's say I only want the results that start with `ndr`

The issue is that wherever the regex I put in the text box it doesnt seem to filter what I want.

What's the correct way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried something like `[^a].*` to filter out values starting with `a`? And even beter: show what exactly you tried, and how it failed you.

Comment: @markalex I see a result being removed that ends with the text *-uat. But let's say I only want results that start with the text "Digital" how can I do it?

Comment: Please [edit] the question, and include your input data, with expected results per sample. Additionally it wouldn't hurt if you include you current regex.

Comment: @markalex I cannot put exactly the results because this is a client project but can give example of results. I tried some regex (Im not expert at it) and nothing worked to do filtering.

Comment: To get simply those that start with `ndr` you can simply use `ndr.*`, or maybe `ndr-.*` if you mean starting with `ndr-`, and not `ndra-` for example. Is that what you want?